# Vapor barrier for crawl space

Tags: moisture, crawlspace

We have a home at Oak Island NC. Our home was built in the 70's. There were no mildew or mold problem until we had plastic put in our crawl space. After a few years we now have the mold problem so we had dehumidifiers installed. The soil is sandy. Thinking about removing the vapor barrier. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: In my experience it is usually the opposite, possibly the barrier is trapping moisture under the plastic and attaching it to the bottom of the floor joists may work I have seen it done both ways.

Comment: Was the plastic added on the ground or attached to the bottom of the floor joists?

Comment: We’re the dehumidifiers added in the house or in the crawl space?